# Page not loading after mocking user-object

Tags: playwright

I have the following step before each test:

```js
test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  await page.route('*/**/user', async (route) => {
    await route.fulfill({ json: JSON.stringify(APP_USER) });
  });
});
```

Inside the Playwright UI, I can verify, that the mock is working and returning the expected payload.

However, calling `page.goto()` is not working as in the page itself remains blank/white. The URL is correct as well.

What could be the reason for this to get stuck:

```js
test(`${APP_USER.name}`, async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(someUrl);
  // ..
  await expect(something).toHaveCount(0);
});
```

Please also note that if I am removing the data-mock, everything is working fine. Without intercepting `*/**/user`, the request will go to a local dev-deployment.

This does not make any sens to me. However, I am new to Playwright and it's possible that I am missing something here.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when the page is white? What URL is the page on when it's white?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `*/**/user` routes more requests than just one.

Try to log all your requests first and find the one that blocks the page from loading

```js
  await page.route("*/**/user", async (route) => {
    console.log("route", route.request().url());
  });
```

And then adjust with better URL regex.